# Sonarqube 5.4 - How to get a list of all rules violated against a project?

Tags: sonarqube-5.4

May be this is something very straightforward but I'm struggling to find how can I get a list of all failed rules (not issues) against a project.
Currently when I go to the Issues tab for a project and click on "Rules" filter, it only shows 15 rules at the max and then shows a search box, but I cant figure out how can I see all violated rules in one go. As it can be seen that the total of all 15 rules is less than the total issues seen on top, but I can't see how I can group the issues by all rules, and not just 15 that show by default? How can I know which other rules have failed?

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?